# Two SQL queries with the same result but one is a order of magnitude faster

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I am wondering why the first query is so much faster than the second.
It is run on a table of around 500k records.

```
SELECT date  FROM `log` WHERE `action` = 'SOMETHING' and token = 167  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;  
-- 0.0003 sec

SELECT max(date)  FROM `log` WHERE `action` = 'SOMETHING' and token = 167; 
-- 0.0023 sec
```

Comment: Because the first query just analyse the first register, and the second need read all the table

Comment: I think your ID column is indexed and that makes a lot of difference.

Comment: To understand performance, you need to provide the `explain` plans for the queries.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name in the end of query have the command `LIMIT 1`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry, the correct word is record.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you don't have an index on date, but DO have an index on id (Primary key)?

If id is a primary key, it can sort the data to return results to you in much quicker. This is because even though your query only returns a date column, the rows are being ORDERED by id, which is indexed, allowing 500k rows to be ordered VERY quickly.

To return the maximum date, even if its one row of a single column ... if date isn't indexed, the database needs to examine EVERY row record to determine which is the largest.

Answer (score 0):

Both queries will run very quickly with an index on `log(action, token, id)`.

To understand the performance differences between those two queries, please give the `explain` plan for them.  You can get this by preceding the queries with `explain`:

```
explain SELECT date  FROM `log` WHERE `action` = 'SOMETHING' and token = 167  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;  

explain SELECT max(date)  FROM `log` WHERE `action` = 'SOMETHING' and token = 167;
```

Answer (score 0):

The first command sorts the table and brings the first record. The second command although not ordering, the db need to read the entire table to find out which is the highest record. Also your table probably does not have index for the field date

Answer (score 0):

These two queries are very different logic, although possibly they return the same value because of a correlation between id's and dates that makes sense to you, but which the query optimiser clearly cannot know.

With an index on (action, token, date) the optimiser may be able to perform the second query faster, but if you're absolutely sure of that correlation then there's nothing wrong with using the first query.